# what is a blacklist in C++?

Tags: c++, c++17

what is a blacklist in C++ (thread) and how can it be deleted

When I run the program it just loads and nothing happens, I use a thread function. I heard that I have a blacklist and that I should delete it. I've debugged the code and after `int valueSQLQuery = f.get ();` nothing happens anymore.

```
int qstate;

int SQLQuery(std::string ID)
{
    MYSQL* conn;
    MYSQL_ROW row;
    MYSQL_RES* res;
    char* key;
    conn = mysql_init(0);

    mysql_real_connect(conn, "localhost", "EQ", "passwor...", "eq", 3306, NULL, 0);

    if (conn) {

        std::ostringstream str;
        str << "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID='" << ID <<"';";
        std::string sql = str.str();

        qstate = mysql_query(conn, sql.c_str());
        if (!qstate) {
            res = mysql_store_result(conn);
            if (res->row_count == 0) {

                return 0;
            }
            while (row = mysql_fetch_row(res)) {
                if (row[0] == ID) {
                    if (atoi(row[7]) == 1) {
                        return 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        return 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

```
std::promise<int> p;
    auto f = p.get_future();
    std::thread SQLQuery(SQLQuery, ID);
    SQLQuery.join();
    int valueSQLQuery = f.get();

    //int valueSQLQuery = SQLQuery(ID);
    if (valueSQLQuery == 0 || ID.length() != 13 || ID == "0") {
    ...
    ...
    }
```

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "blacklist", but just wanted to warn that `str << "SELECT * FROM users WHERE UserID='" << ID <<"';";` is definitely a candidate for an sql injection. Use parameterized queries if possible.

Comment: How does this compile `std::thread SQLQuery(SQLQuery, ID);`? The variable and the function have the same name, my compiler rejects that.

Comment: @TedKleinBergman How, for example, are such inquiries made?

Comment: @prog-fh He gives me 'SQLQuery {_Thr = {_ Hnd = 0x0000000000000788 _Id = 2736}} std :: thread' out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no C++ specific meaning for "blacklist".

In general, "blacklist" typically means a list of entities that are to be excluded.